# Como criar um dropdownButton reutilizável em Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Pretendo criar um `dropdown` reutilizável com `Flutter`, que seja capaz de receber diferentes listas de valores como argumento. No entanto, recebo um erro ao criar uma variável que irá armazenar o valor padrão da lista.
Este é o meu código:

```
class AndroidDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  AndroidDropdown({@required this.sourceList});
  final List<String> sourceList;

  @override
  _AndroidDropdownState createState() => _AndroidDropdownState();
}

class _AndroidDropdownState extends State<AndroidDropdown> {
  // O erro está aqui
  String selectedItem = widget.sourceList[0];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];

    for (String sourceListItem in widget.sourceList) {
      DropdownMenuItem<String> newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(sourceListItem),
        value: sourceListItem,
      );

      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedItem,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedItem = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

O erro é:

> "The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente fazer esta declaração dentro do método [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html):

```
String selectedItem;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedItem = widget.sourceList[0];
}
```

(Esse método deverá ser sobrescrito na sua classe de estado, `_AndroidDropdownState`.)

A linha estava dando erro porque ela era executada no momento da criação da classe `_AndroidDropdownState`. Nesse momento, você não pode acessar a propriedade `widget` pois esta depende de uma instância dessa classe, dando o erro.
O método `initState` é chamado quando o objeto é inserido na árvore de widgets, e portanto a property `widget` já existirá.